# Running a service(started inside a batch file) in background even after closing the parent batch file

Tags: batch-file

On Windows, I have a batch file which starts cassandra and does some other stuff. When the batch file terminated the cassandra is also terminated.

But I have to keep on running cassandra in background and have to terminate it manually.

Can anyone guide me for the same?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the relevant code from your batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [`START`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command?

> START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]

So your `.bat` file might look like this:

```
@echo off
echo starting Cassandra...
START "c:\program files\Cassandra\Cassandra.exe"
echo continuing to process code...
REM more code here
```

Comment: START /B CALL .../path/cassandra/bin/cassandra.bat

Comment: Please edit your original question to include the contents of the batch file.

Comment: Also I have updated my answer. It *may* be more useful now. If not, we need to see your code.